# Como obtener el valor de un select para usarlo en otro componente en react

Tags: reactjs

Hola a todos estoy aprendiendo react y estoy pegado con esto, tengo este codigo que me devuelve un lista en un select, lo que necesito es cuando selecciono un valor de la lista,
ese valor guardarlo en una variable para ocuparlo en cualquier otro lado. el select funciona bien solo me falta guardar la variable,he buscado y he visto tutoriales pero no puedo hacerlo.
se agradece cualquier ayuda.
Gracias.

```
    import { useState } from "react"

export function Botonbuscar(props) {


  const [selectsRegion, setRegion] = useState('Metropolitana de Santiago')

  function cambioRegion(e) {
    setRegion(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div div className="filtroregion">
      <select value={selectsRegion} onChange={cambioRegion} >
        <option>01- Tarapacá</option>
        <option>02- Antofagasta</option>
        <option>03- Atacama</option>
        <option>04- Coquimbo</option>
        <option>05- Valparaíso</option>
        <option>06- O'Higgins</option>
        <option>07- Maule</option>
        <option>08- BioBio</option>
        <option>09- Araucanía</option>
        <option>10- Los Lagos</option>
        <option>11-Aysén del Gral. Carlos Ibáñez del Campo</option>
        <option>12- Magallanes y de la Antartica Chilena</option>
        <option>Metropolitana de Santiago</option>
        <option>14- Los Ríos</option>
        <option>15- Arica y Parinacota</option>

      </select>


    </div>

  );
```

}

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]. Cuál es el problema específico? Veo que a los `option` de tu select le falta el atributo `value`. Puedes leer más sobre esto en esta [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#ejemplos)

Comment: Hola! No comprendo bien...

Quieres que al momento de seleccionar una opción, se guarde en una variable, pero justamente tienes tu variable `selectsRegion` que tiene la opción que hayas seleccionado. Puedes usar esa variable para mostrar o ocuparla en cualquier otro lado que desees.